# Angular directive unit testing setup and teardown

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am unit testing some Angular directives in Jasmine and running the tests with Karma in the PhantomJS headless browser.

I have a couple hundred specs. Since I've started testing the directives, I noticed that PhantomJS takes up a huge chunk of memory after running through the whole test suite a couple of times.  I have a hunch that this is because the directives (and perhaps other garbage) isn't being freed up after they have been tested.

I do have some `afterEach` statements that remove the "compiled" directives after use, but it seems this is not enough, or I am not doing it correctly.

**example.spec.js**

```
describe('leftNavigation', function() {
    var nlElement = angular.element('<div left-navigation></div>');

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('path/to/leftNavigation.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, _$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        template = $templateCache.get('full/path/to/leftNavigation.html');
        $templateCache.put('full/path/to/leftNavigation.html', template);

        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it('should contain the text BLAH', function() {
        var element = $compile(nlElement)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(element.text()).toContain('BLAH');
    });

    // Teardown
    afterEach(function() {
        (nlElement).remove();
    });
});
```

Am I tearing down the right variable (`nlElement`), or do I need to teardown `element` instead?  Do I need `afterEach` statements for every `beforeEach` statement?

**EDIT: The directive is defined as so:**

```
'use strict';

// Grab ref to app module
var app = angular.module('app');

app.directive('leftNavigation', ['$log', 
    function ($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
            scope:{
                selection: '@'
            }
        };
    }
]); //end of directive
```

**EDIT 2: The directive's HTML template does include AngularJS expressions and `ng-class` attributes on multiple elements.**

Comment: Maybe your directive create eentListeners in DOM elements and you dont clean those on the `$destroy` event of the scope of your directive

Comment: @Raulucco I added the code for the directive.  I am not sure if it is creating eventListeners.

Comment: I haven't experienced this and I have a larger testing suite than that.  I think it's more likely that some of your directives have code that is causing memory leaks, as Raulucco says

Comment: It looks like is a known issue with [PhantonJS](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/55)

Comment: Maybe use PhantomJS 2. Although it's not a stable release, it fixed a lot of issues, and made our unit tests (which look similar to yours) run 1.2x faster with no intermittent crashes (because of memory issues).